# use a macro to show the stringified content of a macro

Tags: c++, debugging, arduino, macros, preprocessor

I am writing code for an Arduino. The code starts to get long so I want to use some debugging macros, and to be able to show some debugging information on serial port.

For example, I have some macros to define which serial ports I use:

```
#define SERIAL_GPS Serial1
#define SERIAL_IRIDIUM Serial2
#define SERIAL_VN100 Serial3
```

How can I write a macro to show the ports I use for each one? I.e. some macro that would print on a debug serial port:

```
Port for GPS: Serial1
Port for Iridium: Serial2
Port for VN100: Serial3
```

I have tried:

```
#define SHOW_VAR_NAME(x) #x
```

together with:

```
SERIAL_DEBUG.println(SHOW_VAR_NAME(SERIAL_GPS));
```

But this prints on serial:

```
SERIAL_GPS
```

instead of:

```
Serial1
```

because (I guess) the macro pre-processor does only one scan. Any smart way to get this to work?

Note: I take a simple example here, but there are some debug variables (for example, some variables DEBUG_GPS, DEBUG_IRIDIUM and others) that I would really like to print at board startup: I have quite a few of those debug options for separate components, and printing their status at startup would help keep track of which debuggings are activated or not (even if they are all gathered in a header file, it would not hurt to remember the user about all of them).

Comment: Any time someone asks a macro question here - I would highlight the suggestion of "look into the mirror, and ask yourself if there's truely not a better way".

Comment: @UKMonkey : I am still quite close to a beginner, but the more I encounter macros the more I agree with you. If you have any suggestions of another way to organize my code, I will be very interested. Also please note that this is for Arduino boards as written in the question, ie an architecture with about 32kB flash and 1kB RAM (quite dependent on which specific mC). This is a bit special requirements ;)

Comment: Well, not knowing what `Serial1` is; I'm going to assume it's an integer to report which port `Serial1` is on... in which case create a function called `getPortUsage(int port)` and then you can `switch(port) {case SERIAL_GPS: return "GPS";}`  This should impact your mem usage less than you'd expect; especially if you inline it or even constexpr it

Comment: No, sorry for not giving more context: again this is Arduino code, with all the conventions it implies ;) So if I am right Serial1 is a full serial object (interrupt driven serial port).

Comment: but I see the logics in your method ;) (even if there will be some cost associated to it compared with a macro; a switch should not be too bad, but it quickly adds up on so small architectures I would think).

Comment: Wrap it in your own object then ... `class GPSSerial { public: Serial& getSerial(){}  const char* getName(){return "GPS";}`

Comment: 4MHz clock speed ... switch statement is probably 4-5 cycles tops.  A million of them will take a second.  How many are you planning to do?

Comment: Not too many, you are right. If there is a simple macro solution, as the accepted answer, I like it well though ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`#` preprocessor operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators) prevents the expansion of its operand. You need to add a layer of indirection so that expansion can occur:

```
#define SHOW_VAR_NAME_(x) #x
#define SHOW_VAR_NAME(x) SHOW_VAR_NAME_(x)
```

This functionality is provided by [`BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/stringize.html) from Boost.Preprocessor, which I recommend using if you start using the preprocessor heavily.

Comment: IOW, re-implement `BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE`.

Comment: @Angew I plead guilty of FGITW. I'm actually fetching Boost.PP's documentation right now.

Comment: Many thanks, for both the answer (this works great) and pointing to boost. Do you think using boost.preprocessor will be ok on Arduino mCs (typically 32kB Flash, 1kB ram), or that there will be some costs to it?

Comment: @Zorglub29 it's all preprocessor, so no footprint at all :)

Comment: ok, thank you :) Will look at it in details when I have some time then ;)

Comment: The strings may be generated by the preprocessor, but you are going to be doing something with them. And once they get compiled into the final executable image, there *is* a memory footprint. At 1kB RAM even tiny strings can turn out to be show stoppers.